# Changing textColor for searchTextField

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I have UISearchController and I want to change the textColor of the search field.

For my surprise

```
searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .red
```

did not change the color of the search field, also none of this worked:

```
   searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "test", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
   searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.tintColor = .red
   UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).textColor = .red
```

The only thing that worked for me is

```
searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.delegate = self
....
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) // became first responder
{
    //textField's textColor is white for some reason
    textField.textColor = .red
}
```

I guess this must be something specific to my project. Is there anyone else having the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use following code. It will work

```
if let textfield = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
 textfield.textColor = UIColor.red
}
```